# Identify if a Type is *either* of int or Nullable<int>

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable, typechecking

Reflection code.

I can check if
    myTypeObject == typeof(decimal) || myTypeObject  == typeof(decimal?)

Is there any way to do that without repeating `decimal`?

I'm guessing something along the lines of:

```
myRealTypeObject = myTypeObject.IsNullable() ? myTypeObject.GetTypeInsideNullability() : myTypeObject;
myRealTypeObject == typeof(decimal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` which returns null if the input type is not nullable:

```
var myRealTypeObject = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(myTypeObject) ?? myTypeObject;
```

if instead you have have some object you want to check you can just use `is` (or `as`):

```
bool isDecimal = boxedDecimal is decimal?;
```

Comment: it's specifically reflection code (EF type conventions, if you care), but the 1st half is exactly what I was hoping for.